How to get a correct circle on a cylinder with inset?
I'm learning basic blender skills for creating some primitive WIP models for learning Godot. Here I have cylinder and I want to make a wheel, but when I use Inset on this face I get this:

How do I get correct circle with it? It is just newly created cylinder which is moved and scaled just a bit. I checked this also on default, newly created cylinder and it is same.

Your cylinder have a non uniform scale. Switch to Object mode, press Ctrl+A then Scale to apply the scale (make it 1 in every axis). Except if you really need it, it is a good practice to always apply object scales to avoid such confusing behaviors.
The object scale can be seen here in the N panel > Item:


Thank you! But this not exact;y hepled because this cylinder is part of another object (car), and if I sacale whole object to 1 on every axis, it becomig deformed. Howewer, I resolve this problem another way: I create separate object (cylinder), than make what I need with circle face in it, and then I joined it to car.

But at least now I know reason why this happened so your answer helped anyway!

Oh I got it! But that take me one day to understand =) At a first time I do not get what means "apply scale", now I know. Thank you again!

You're welcome :D
